# d3 loop through local data variable to make stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have no problem modifying the stacked barchart from [this example](http://www.delimited.io/blog/2014/3/3/creating-multi-series-charts-in-d3-lines-bars-area-and-streamgraphs) (thanks Steven Hall), which uses a `.csv` file as its data source. I just change the csv to my data, and presto.

But when I try to get it to work using data in a different format (local json variable generated in a php application), it won't cooperate.

This is the code with the .csv:

```
     d3.csv('_Poll_nonPoll_.csv', function (error, data) { 
// draw chart
});
```

This is mine:

```
     var data5_pre = [[{'hour':1,'Good':15000,'Bad':4000}],[{'hour':2,'Good':16000,'Bad':1000}],[{'hour':3,'Good':17000,'Bad':1500}],[{'hour':4,'Good':18000,'Bad':1100}]];

function makeChart(data5){ /* this line replaces the d3.csv */
      var data5 = data5_pre[0];
      var labelVar = 'hour';

      var varNames = d3.keys(data5[0])
          .filter(function(key) {
              return key !== labelVar;
          });


          color.domain(varNames);


          data5.forEach(function(d) {
              var y0 = 0;
              d.mapping = varNames.map(function(name) {
                  return {
                      name: name,
                      label: d[labelVar],
                      y0: y0,
                      y1: y0 += +d[name]
                  };
              });
              d.total = d.mapping[d.mapping.length - 1].y1;
          });

          console.log('prepped data5', data5);

          x.domain(data5.map(function(d) {
              return d.hour;
          }));
          y.domain([0, d3.max(data5, function(d) {
              return d.total;
          })]);

          var selection = svg.selectAll('.series')
              .data(data5)
              .enter().append('g')
              .attr('class', 'series')
              .attr('transform', function(d) {
                  return 'translate(' + x(d.hour) + ',0)';
              });

          selection.selectAll('rect')
              .data(function(d) {
                  return d.mapping;
              })
              .enter().append('rect')
              .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
              .attr('y', function(d) {
                  return y(d.y1);
              })
              .attr('height', function(d) {
                  return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1);
              })
              .style('fill', function(d) {
                  return color(d.name);
              })
              .style('stroke', 'grey');
}
makeChart(data5_pre);
```

As you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vogL5zw6/), mine only draws a single column, of hour 1 data.

I feel stupid, this should be easy. But whatever `for` loop I try (focusing on the the `data5.forEach` part), I get the same exact result (if it doesn't break).

I'm stumped. Anybody have an idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two glitches in your code:

1. The structure of your `data5_pre` does not correspond to the one, which will be provided by `d3.csv()`. This function will pass the parsed rows as an array of objects to the callback. In your code it is an array of arrays having one object each. This should be corrected as follows:

   ```
   var data5_pre = [{
     'hour': 1,
     'Good': 15000,
     'Bad': 4000
   }, {
     'hour': 2,
     'Good': 16000,
     'Bad': 1000
   }, {
     'hour': 3,
     'Good': 17000,
     'Bad': 1500
   }, {
     'hour': 4,
     'Good': 18000,
     'Bad': 1100
   }];
   ```
2. Inside your function `makeChart(data)` you are using a flawed assignment

   ```
   var data5 = data5_pre[0];
   ```

   This needs to be corrected to:

   ```
   var data5 = data5_pre;
   ```

See the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vogL5zw6/1/) for a working example.

Comment: that worked. thanks so much. I got stuck looking for a way to deal with the array of arrays, instead of just changing the way I made the array in the first place. Much appreciated.